# Support iOS 8 - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Do I need to learn and convert my entire codebase to the new Swift language if I want to  support ios 8?

Comment: No Swift and Objectivce-C will live side by side for now.

Comment: Not only will you have to convert all your code by hand, but companies will only hire developers with at least three years of Swift experience.

Comment: By my understanding, on one at Apple even talks about retiring  Objective-C. A new language is not to be taking lightly, it will need to age long before such talks will take place. IMHO of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** The APIs available from Swift are exactly the same as the APIs available from Objective-C; you can code against any iOS 8 APIs from either language.

To start writing in Swift, there's an option called [Migration.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html) It will convert your existing code into swift code

> Migration provides an opportunity to revisit an existing Objective-C
>   app and improve its architecture, logic, and performance by replacing
>   pieces of it in Swift. For a straightforward, incremental migration of
>   an app, you’ll be using the tools learned earlier—mix and match plus
>   interoperability. Mix-and-match functionality makes it easy to choose
>   which features and functionality to implement in Swift, and which to
>   leave in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

NO. 
Your Swift code can be run alongside your Objective-C code because Swift is built with the same compiler, ARC management and runtime as Objective-C.